# link set as absolute link doesnt work

Tags: php, html

I have got that link:

```
<a href="index.php">Political Science</a>
```

I put it dynamically with php code "include" as part of a  header.. now, it doesnt work, that is because it depends where I am in the website directory.. sometimes I am two folders inside sometimes, I am at the root. .. henceforth, the value of the href attribute is incorrect when I am not in the root but in some folder.. it should be ../index.php..

How can I adapt that attribute to be ../index.php or index.php depending where I navigate in my site?

Comment: I was about to say `<base href=..>` but it sounds you do have a nested path structure, and just that one link needs to be absolute. But why does a proper `href=/index.php` not work for you?

Comment: simply "index.php" isn't  an absolute link. Placing a '/' in front of the href will automatically shoot to your home folder, that way you can specify the exact location regardless of where in the heiarchy you are in. -> "/index.php" if index.php is in the root.

Comment: you may use absolute path: `'<a href="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php">'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this, I usually assign an absolute path to the href attributes. I keep the address of my website in a variable and concatinate the website address with the relative location of the file (relative to the physical root of the website) like this:

```
$domain      = "http://www.google.com/";
$absoluteURL = $domain . "folderx/foldery/zzz.html"

<a href=<?php echo $absoluteURL; ?>">Political Science</a>
```

and this never fails

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__FILE__`, `dirname()` and `explode()`, but it's a bit dirty way. You can define global constant in somefile.php and check it in file which you include and e.g. if it's true, add ../ at the beginning of the link.

Answer (score 0):

So you want that link to always go to the same index?  Why not just use an absolute href like this:

```
<a href="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/index.php">
```

(Like k102 said)

Answer (score -2):

You can write

```
$path = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/index.php";

<a href="<?php echo $path;?>">Political Science</a>
```

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is not always guaranteed be your own domain and also it can be a full path to a page not just a domain name.

Comment: why do I need the back page path?!?